# sbt.properties with XPages

Tags: ibm-sbt

In the install guide was explained about the sbt.properties file, with references to the different environments.
In XPages you normally use the xsp.properties files.
Should I copy the references from sbt.properties to xsp.properties, to take advantage of these references.
There was also mentioned to include these variable by %{variable name}. Is it possible to use such a syntax in my faces-config.xml in my Domino database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SBT code uses both managed beans and properties. In case of a Java EE server, and when JSF in not in the mix, we implemented from scratch. In case of XPages, we actually use what is already implemented by the XPages framework. This means that it uses the properties defined in xsp.properties, and the JSF managed beans, defined in the regular faces-config.xml. Because the JSF framework doesn't support the property substitution in the managed bean definition files, this functionality is not available to XPagesNow, in JSF, the property values can also be computed using an EL expression: #{...}. This is not as easy to use, but can help.

Comment: As I look in the xsp.properties of Social Enabler database I see there a reference to a managed bean, like 'extlib.endpoint.connections=connectionsLtpa'. So how do I use this syntax if I want to use the endpoints of the SBT SDK.

Answer (score 2):

The SDK uses factories to load the managed beans and properties used for configuration i.e. endpoint definitions, environments, password stores etc. The SDK contains an extension point for defining the factories and includes standard factories for reading configuration files from classpath or WEB-INF folder of your web application. Additionally the SBT playground has some code which can read this data from a Notes DB.
We are working on including at the SDK in Domino and Domino Designer in an upcoming release. So in the meantime some development is needed.
I'll be creating a sample which illustrates how to create a custom bean and proeprties factory (request that came up at the Dublin workshop). As part of that I'll look at this request also.
Phil also may have some ideas on how to reuse the code used by the playground.
- Mark

Comment: Is there anything new with the mentioned sample and ideas?